# iOS Sharing Image to LinkedIn using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, image, share, linkedin-api, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to share image to all possible apps installed in my device.
But unfortunately, I'm not able to post image successfully to LinkedIn (already installed and logged in as verified user).

LinkedIn is being displayed in list of share actions in UIActivityViewController, when I tap on it, It displays a dialogue with image, which I have added as activity item, but it is not being posted to LinkedIn.

Tested successfully for Google+, FB and Twitter.

If I share url, then it gets posted to LinkedIn app. Only image is not being posted.

I got these lines in Console Log:

```
2015-05-06 19:27:54.369 Share[1659:309834] LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called 2015-05-06 19:27:59.824 Share[1659:309793] plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension invalidated
```

Here is the code i'm trying:

```
- (IBAction)openShare:(id)sender{
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test1.jpg"];
NSString *str = @"iOS";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[img1,url,str]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:^{
                                     NSLog(@"completed");
                                 }];
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem. Anytime i try to share a photo, even when is only a photo i get an error and the share is not performed correctly.

As a solution i'm not sharing the photo when the activityType is **com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension**

Comment: yes. definately, it is the way to avoid errors, but my client want linkedin to be removed if it is unable to share my photo. Is there any way to remove linkedin from the activities?

Comment: How do you intercept the activityType in order to remove the image before the plugin is shown?

Comment: You can remove an activity with the help of the `excludedActivityTypes` property of the `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: Excellent! It's help me a lot! Thanks.

Comment: @portella, how do you "not share the photo"