# Unable to share text and url using UIActivityViewController to LinkedIn

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to share text and url using UIActivityViewController. Its working for all other application except LinkedIn. I am always getting error

> plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension invalidated

have a look at below code

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It shows linkedin sharing Popup. but on post it shows error. 
I have even tried with only text, but no luck with LinkedIn.

Please also suggest how can I exclude share extension other than com.apple.UIKit.activity

Comment: just see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079344/ios-sharing-image-to-linkedin-using-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I already looked that thread, but I am not sharing any image in the post. Sharing only text is not even working.

Comment: can you suggest how can I exclude LinkedIn. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can **try with API POST request**

*Once your mobile users have authenticated, you can use the ApiHelper.postRequest() method to POST share data from your mobile application.*

here payload will be your stuff:

```
NSString *url = [NSString initWithString:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];

NSString *payload = [NSString initWithString:@"{
    \"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG\",
    \"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\" }
}"];

if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) {
    [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] postRequest:url stringBody:payload
    success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {
        // do something with response
    }
    error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
        // do something with error
    }];
]}
```

[Reference official docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)